# Convert a string with hex values to an array array of boolean values in php

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, hex

I found a clever bit of code in the site I'm working on that uses hex values to store an array of toggleable variables.

(For example, D in hex being 1101 in binary, means the first toggle is one, the second is off, and the third and fourth are on).

I looked at unpack, but either I didn't understand it or it's not the right function for me. I also considered splitting the whole thing character by character and then sending each character through a switch that then drops values into an array, but that seems way too cumbersome and inelegant.

So, how do I turn a string of hex-based characters into an ordered array of Boolean values?

Comment: So you want to convert a string like: `"D"` into an array, like: `Array ( True, True, False, True )` ?

Comment: What about, for example, hex digit `1`? Should the resulting array be `[True]` or `[False, False, False, True]` or something else?

Comment: @lafor
1 should be False, False, False, True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
function hex_to_bool_array($hex_string, $pad_length = 0) {
   return array_map(
      function($v) { return (bool) $v; },
      str_split(str_pad(base_convert($hex_string, 16, 2), $pad_length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT))
   );
}

var_dump(hex_to_bool_array('D'));

// array (size=4)
//   0 => boolean true
//   1 => boolean true
//   2 => boolean false
//   3 => boolean true;

var_dump(hex_to_bool_array('7', 8));

// array (size=8)
// 0 => boolean false
// 1 => boolean false
// 2 => boolean false
// 3 => boolean false
// 4 => boolean false
// 5 => boolean true
// 6 => boolean true
// 7 => boolean true
```

Comment: `decbin(hexdec($hex_string))` Why not just: `base_convert($hex_string, 16, 2)` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Good point, I forgot there's `base_convert()`. Thanks.